# Textarea resize JS script bug

Tags: javascript, forms, debugging, textarea

I'm trying to fix a bug in the JavaScript I wrote to resize the `<textarea>` of my form.

I want it to resize based on the number of text lines. Ideally, the bottom line should follow.

Form link: [LorenzoMengolini.com/contact](https://lorenzomengolini.com/contact)

```html
<script>
(function($) { 
var span = $('<span>').css('display','inline-block')
.css('word-break','break-all').appendTo('body').css('visibility','hidden');
function initSpan(textarea){
  span.text(textarea.text())
      .width(textarea.width())      
      .css('font',textarea.css('font'));
}
$('textarea').on({
    input: function(){
      var text = $(this).val();      
      span.text(text);      
      $(this).height(text ? span.height() : '1.1em');
    },
    focus: function(){
     initSpan($(this));
    },
    keypress: function(e){
        if(e.which == 13) e.preventDefault();
    }
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this code better than a javascript function?

```html
<textarea name="text" oninput='this.style.height = "";this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + "px"'></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @djcaesar9114 

I already implemented it on the page. you can see the results here https://lorenzomengolini.com/contact

The only issue is that when text is deleted the textarea doesn't go back to the original size. is it possible to fix this?

Many thanks for the support